# Reducing integer attributes in a list of objects

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, reduction, collectors

I have a model of this structure

```
public class MyModel {
        private long firstCount;
        private long secondCount;
        private long thirdCount;
        private long fourthCount;

        public MyModel(firstCount,secondCount,thirdCount,fourthCount) 
        {
        }
        //Getters and setters

}
```

Assume that I have a list of these models with the following data

```
MyModel myModel1 = new MyModel(10,20,30,40);
MyModel myModel2 = new MyModel(50,60,70,80);

List<MyModel> modelList = Arrays.asList(myModel1, myModel2);
```

Supposing I want to find out the sum of  firstCount in all the models, I could do this

```
Long collect = modelList.stream().collect
(Collectors.summingLong(MyModel::getFirstCount));
```

*What if I want to find out sum of  attributes in all the models in one pass ?Is there any way to achieve this ?*

the output should be something like

- sum of  firstCount = 60
- sum of  secondCount = 80
- sum of  thirdCount = 100
- sum of  fourthCount = 120

Comment: Do you mean `long collect = modelList.stream().mapToLong(MyModel::getFirstCount).sum();`? Unless you have a special stream source that can’t be traversed more than once (which is not the case in your example), doing four operations like the one shown above, is the simplest and (in most cases) most efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `MyModel` as accumulator:

```
MyModel reduced = modelList.stream().reduce(new MyModel(0, 0, 0, 0), (a, b) ->
                      new MyModel(a.getFirstCount() + b.getFirstCount(),
                                  a.getSecondCount() + b.getSecondCount(),
                                  a.getThirdCount() + b.getThirdCount(),
                                  a.getFourthCount() + b.getFourthCount()));
System.out.println(reduced.getFirstCount());
System.out.println(reduced.getSecondCount());
System.out.println(reduced.getThirdCount());
System.out.println(reduced.getFourthCount());
```

Comment: @OP Alternatively, you could make an ```add(MyModel)``` method on ```MyModel```. That adds the values of the passed model to ```this``` model, and then returns ```this```. That would make the second argument ```(a, b) -> a.add(b)```, without the need to allocate a new object.

Answer (score 1):

What you may do is create a method `add(MyModel)` that returns a new instance of `MyModel` and use the `reduce` method of `Stream` and also, `@Override` `toString()`

```
public MyModel add(MyModel model) {
    long first = firstCount + model.getFirstCount();
    long second = secondCount + model.getSecondCount();
    long third = thirdCount + model.getThirdCount();
    long fourth = fourthCount + model.getFourthCount();


    return new MyModel(first, second, third, fourth);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "sum of firstCount = " + firstCount + "\n"
        +  "sum of secondCount = " + secondCount + "\n"
        +  "sum of thirdCount = " + thirdCount + "\n"
        +  "sum of fourthCount = " + fourthCount;
}
```

---

### Without Identity

```
String result = modelList.stream()
                         .reduce((one, two) -> one.add(two))
                         .orElse(new MyModel(0,0,0,0))
                         .toString();
```

---

### With Identity

```
String result = modelList.stream()
                         .reduce(new MyModel(0,0,0,0), (one, two) -> one.add(two))
                         .toString();
```